# Java generic compile time error migrating from Java 6 to 7 or 8

Tags: java, generics, compilation, compiler-errors

We've started getting compile errors on code that used generics and that compiled successfully under Java 6. Here's a simple class to reproduce:

```
class Test {
    static class Foo<T> {
            T t;
            Foo(T t) { this.t = t; }
            T get() { return t; }
    }

    static class Bar extends Foo<Long> {
            Bar(Long t) { super(t); }
    }

    static class Foobar<N extends Number> extends Bar {
            Foobar() { super(5L); }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Bar bar = new Bar(0L);
            Long b = bar.get();             // This works
            Foobar foobar = new Foobar();
            Long fb = foobar.get(); // This generates a compile time error
    }
}
```

The resulting error is:

```
Test.java:26: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Long
            Long fb = foobar.get(); // This generates a compile time error
```

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, didn't mention that the compile errors happen in Java 7 and 8, but not in 6...

Comment: Oddly, while I get this compile error using jdk1.7.0_13 from the command line, this code compiles fine in eclipse, using the same compiler (double checked that the "installed JRE" is pointing to the same path, and that the compliance level is 1.7, and using that jdk).

Comment: I got exactly the same - Eclipse compiled this with 1.8 set without an error.  Very strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `Foobar` without any type parameters is a *raw type*. Raw types have no generic abilities, so in this case the raw type `Foobar` extends `Bar` which extends the *raw* type `Foo`. Raw types use the upper bound of their parameters, as they are compiled that way after erasure and the compiler has no type parameters to safely insert casts.

In the case of `Foo`, this upper bound is `Object`. This causes `Foo.get()` to return `Object`, so `Bar.get()` returns `Object`, and so `Foobar.get()` returns `Object` as well. Obviously, the compiler won't cast `Object` to `Long` without an explicit cast.

In contrast, the parameterized type `Foobar<N>` extends `Bar` which extends the parameterized type `Foo<Long>`. The compiler can now use generics, so it sees that `Foo<T>.get()` has type `T`, that `Foo<Long>.get()` has type `Long`, that `Bar.get()` has type `Long`, and finally that `Foobar<N>.get()` has type `Long` as well.

This means that you should declare `foobar` as shown:

```
Foobar<...> foobar = new Foobar<...>();
```

It doesn't matter what the type parameter of `foobar` is, just as long as it is present. It can even be the wildcard `?`.

Comment: But, why does the raw type work in 1.6? I am not aware of any changes in 1.7 to generics (aside from type inference)

Comment: @radoh I think they just made type checking stricter in 7. Raw types shouldn't exist in modern code, they are only there for compatibility, for types that were updated with generics even though calling code wasn't. Not sure exactly though, best to just check Oracle's release notes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation,  Personally, I think the Java 6 way was more intuitive, and the changes required mean code has to be more long winded.  A generic type instance defined without a parameter should really be treated as the base parameter, in this case Foobar on its own should be treated identically to Foobar<Number>...